# Or Changing Behavior of Word Boundry

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

Below the first Debug returns 'unsbuscrib''d and the second returns unsbuscrib''d.  The difference is the leading '.

What I would like is for both to return unsbuscrib''d.

```
    string textText = " 'unsbuscrib''d' ";
    Regex rTest = new Regex(@"\b(ab)|(['\w]+)\b");
    if (rTest.IsMatch(textText))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(rTest.Match(textText).Value);
    }
    rTest = new Regex(@"\b(['\w]+)\b");
    if (rTest.IsMatch(textText))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(rTest.Match(textText).Value);
    }
```

The fix was @"\b((ab)|(['\w]+))\b" thanks to Guffa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the first regular expression matches `\b(ab)` or `(['\w]+)\b`.

It will include the apostrophe at the beginning, as it uses the second part, where there is no requirement of a word boundary at the beginning.

The second regular expression requires a word boundary at the beginning, and there is no word boundary between the space and the apostrophe. The first word boundary is between the apostrophe and the letter `u`.

Answer (score 0):

A `\b` [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) matches between an alphanumeric character and a non-alnum character, so it matches between `'` and `u` but not between `<space>` and `'`.

And your alternation separates the first regex into

```
\b(ab)   |   (['\w]+)\b
```

Perhaps you meant

```
\b(?:(ab)|(['\w]+))\b
```